# how to split the characters in a string and perform a sum in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a sting with value in it as "12345"
what i have to do is i have to perform a split operation and add that using for loops
like: 1+2+3+4+5
and then display the output of the operation in a label as 15.

i am posting my code here in asp.net and c#

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace proj1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int v1 = 0, x = 0; //sum = 0, l, r;
                               // char Q, W, E, R, T, Y, U, I, O, P, A, S, D, F, G, H, J, K, L, Z, X, C, V, B, N, M;
            string str = TextBox1.Text;
            Label1.Text = ("Result");
            Label2.Text = ("You have Entered");
            Label5.Text = (":");
            Label8.Text = str.ToString();
            // Array word[] = new Array();
            string str1 = str.Replace(" ", "").Replace("`", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("!", "")
                            .Replace("@", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("^", "")
                            .Replace("&", "").Replace("*", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "")
                            .Replace("_", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")
                            .Replace("|", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(";", "")
                            .Replace("'", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("?", "")
                            .Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("1", "").Replace("2", "").Replace("3", "")
                            .Replace("4", "").Replace("5", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("7", "").Replace("8", "")
                            .Replace("9", "").Replace("0", "");
            string str2 = str1.ToUpper();
            string str3 = str2.Replace("A", "1").Replace("B", "2").Replace("C", "3").Replace("D", "4").Replace("E", "5").Replace("F", "8")
                             .Replace("G", "3").Replace("H", "5").Replace("I", "1").Replace("J", "1").Replace("K", "2").Replace("L", "3")
                             .Replace("M", "4").Replace("N", "5").Replace("O", "7").Replace("P", "8").Replace("Q", "1").Replace("R", "2")
                             .Replace("S", "3").Replace("T", "4").Replace("U", "6").Replace("V", "6").Replace("W", "6").Replace("X", "5")
                             .Replace("Y", "1").Replace("Z", "7");
            string word1 = str3.ToString();
            String[] word = word1.ToString().Split();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                x = (( x + (Convert.ToInt32(word[i]))));
            }
            int value1 = x;

            Label3.Text = ("Value Of Charecters");
            Label6.Text = (":");
            Label9.Text = value1.ToString();


            Label4.Text = ("Summed Value");
            Label7.Text = (":");
            Label10.Text = ("");
        }

        }
    }
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="proj1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Project - 1</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">Enter Your Text</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="362px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
      </td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>

</table> 
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Actually i have to perform this task

1. Input Characters in text box. then on button click
2. Save the characters and display the input
3. replace the characters with the given numbers in excel sheet.
4. Perform the sum like if a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5 then you should display
        15 as output as the result of that sum after that.
5. Separate the values in the sum say 15 as 1 and 5 which are inputs for another function for totalling until the final summation should be single digit
6. Generate  exe file

Comment: Holy wall of code, batman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string source = "12345";

  myLabel.Text = source
    .Select(c => c - '0') // character to integer '0' -> 0 .. '9' -> 9  
    .Sum()                // sum up
    .ToString();          // represent as string
```

Comment: Sir if you don't mind i would like to add some code for giving more clear and direct answer for feature reference of people by self replying to this question

Comment: @ROHIT MANDALAPU: It's quite OK since it's you who knows what should have been implemented. So, feel free to provide any code, comments, solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the script is not Java script it is C# code

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace proj1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = TextBox1.Text;
            Label1.Text = ("Result");
            Label2.Text = ("You have Entered");
            Label5.Text = (":");
            Label8.Text = str.ToString();
            string str1 = str.Replace(" ", "").Replace("`", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("!", "")
                            .Replace("@", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("^", "")
                            .Replace("&", "").Replace("*", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "")
                            .Replace("_", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")
                            .Replace("|", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(";", "")
                            .Replace("'", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("?", "")
                            .Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("1", "").Replace("2", "").Replace("3", "")
                            .Replace("4", "").Replace("5", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("7", "").Replace("8", "")
                            .Replace("9", "").Replace("0", "");
            string str2 = str1.ToUpper();
            string str3 = str2.Replace("A", "1").Replace("B", "2").Replace("C", "3").Replace("D", "4").Replace("E", "5").Replace("F", "8")
                             .Replace("G", "3").Replace("H", "5").Replace("I", "1").Replace("J", "1").Replace("K", "2").Replace("L", "3")
                             .Replace("M", "4").Replace("N", "5").Replace("O", "7").Replace("P", "8").Replace("Q", "1").Replace("R", "2")
                             .Replace("S", "3").Replace("T", "4").Replace("U", "6").Replace("V", "6").Replace("W", "6").Replace("X", "5")
                             .Replace("Y", "1").Replace("Z", "7");
            string word1 = str3.ToString();
            string a = word1.Select(c => c - '0').Sum().ToString();
            Label3.Text = ("Sum Of Charecters");
            Label6.Text = (":");
            Label9.Text = a.ToString();
            string w = Label9.ToString();
            string s = w.ToString();
            string b = a.Select(c => c - '0').Sum().ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                string p = b.Select(c => c - '0').Sum().ToString();
                Label10.Text = p.ToString();
            }
            Label4.Text = ("Summed Value");
            Label7.Text = (":");
        }

        }
    }
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="proj1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Project - 1</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">Enter Your Text</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="362px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
      </td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>

</table> 
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string source = "12345";
var sum = 0;
foreach (var element in source)
  sum += Convert.ToInt32(element.ToString());
```